# Difference between "? extends Stream<? extends R>" and "Stream<? extends R>"

Tags: java, generics, wildcard, flatmap

What's the difference between

> ? extends Stream<? extends R>

and

> Stream<? extends R>

Is `<R> Stream<R> flatMap(Function<? super T,? extends Stream<? extends R>> mapper)` same as `<R> Stream<R> flatMap(Function<? super T, Stream<? extends R>> mapper)`.

Could you give some examples?

Comment: `Function<InType, SpecificStreamType>` matches the first but not the second.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: `? extends SomeType` is very different than `SomeType`.

Longer answer:

The use of `Stream<extends R>` as `SomeType` confuses the example.  To answer the question, consider a simpler comparison, for example:

`? extends Integer`

`Integer`

The first observation is that `? extends Integer` as a type expression can be used only within generic declarations.  On the other hand, `Integer` can be used in many more places.

Here are some code examples to help show the difference:

```
    // The following do not compile:
    //
    // Syntax error on tokens, delete these tokens ('? extends').
    //
    // private Integer value;
    // public ? extends Integer getValue() {
    //     return value;
    // }
    //
    // Syntax error on tokens, delete these tokens ('? extends').
    //
    // private Integer value;
    // public void setInteger(? extends Integer value) {
    //     this.value = value;
    // }
    //
    // In both cases, the use of bounded quantification ('? extends') is
    // not valid outside of a generic type declaration.

    // Here is a very basic example of the use of generics:
    //
    // Generic 'Wrapped' is quantified on a single type, which
    // is unrestricted:

    public class Wrapped<T> {
        Wrapped() { this.value = null; }
        Wrapped(T value) { this.value = value; }
        private T value;
        public void set(T value) { this.value = value; }
        public T get() { return value; }
    }

    // The following is also valid:
    //
    // 'Wrapped_1' is quantified on a single type, which is restricted
    // to be 'Integer' or a subtype of 'Integer'.

    public class Wrapped_1<T extends Integer> {
        // EMPTY
    }
    
    // This is not valid.  In addition to being non-valid syntacticly,
    // the declaration needs a specific type.  Use of a wildcard does
    // not provide a specific type.
    //
    // Syntax error on token "?", Identifier expected
    //
    // public class Wrapped_2<? extends Integer> {
    // }

    // The following does not compile:
    //
    // Cannot instantiate the type Wrapped<? extends Integer>.
    // Type mismatch: cannot convert from Wrapped<? extends Integer> to Wrapped<Integer>.
    //
    // private Wrapped<Integer> Wrapped0 = new Wrapped<? extends Integer>();

    // These show the difference in effect between the declarations
    // 'Integer' and '? extends Integer'.

    private Wrapped<Integer> wrapped_1 = new Wrapped<Integer>( new Integer(4) );
    private Wrapped<? extends Integer> wrapped_2 = wrapped_1;
    
    {
        // This compiles:
        wrapped_1.set( new Integer(5) );

        // This does not compile:
        //
        // The method set(capture#1-of ? extends Integer)
        // in the type Wrapped<capture#1-of ? extends Integer>
        // is not applicable for the arguments (Integer)
        //
        // wrapped2.set( new Integer(6) );
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

let say R = Number

Stream<? extends R> can be `Stream<Integer>` `Stream<Long>`

But
`? extends Stream<? extends R>` says which implements `Stream<Number>` or `Stream<Integer>` and so on....
`class XXXX implements Stream<Integer>{}` ...
`XXXX` overrides all the Stream abstract methods